# Do I need a UK visa if I have a visa for Ireland?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, ireland

I have lot of confusion. I am traveling from Bangalore (India) to Dublin (Ireland) and I have a stopover of 4h15m in London Heathrow; I have to change terminals from 2 to 5.

I have valid Irish Join Family Visa and will have a Resident Permit. Do I still need a transit visa for the UK?

And one more thing: my first airline, Air India, will not transfer my luggage to the connecting flight on British Airways.

If a visa is required, can I get the transit visa on arrival?

Comment: @Lalith The UK does not issue visas on arrival, transit or any other type.

Comment: "Dublin Joinspouse Visa with Resident Permit". What exactly do you have? Is it a card or sticker in the passport, and what does it say?

Comment: @Coke it's a long-stay D visa, also called a [*Join Family Visa*](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-long-family-other)

Comment: @Lalith You do **not** need a UK visa

Comment: @Coke, I have a Card and Visa Sticker Both. Yes it is 'D' Visa ... So Can I change the terminals and baggage claim in one terminal and check in another terminal without UK visa ?

Comment: @Lalith Yes you can, 100%. If the check-in staff tries to deny you boarding, point them to TIMATIC. they need to put in NA=IN, AR=IE, DE=DUB and TR=LHR. It will then say "**Visa required, except for Nationals of India with a normal

passport making a landside transit with a confirmed onward
ticket for a flight to a third country that departs before

23:59 the next day. They must: 
- have a "D" visa issued by Ireland (Rep.), and
- clear immigration, and
- have documents required for the next destination.** "